# Windows 10 (64 bit) - Realtek is setting wrong ohms for headphones

Tags: windows-10, audio, motherboard, default-settings, realtek-hd-audio

More detail about my computer motherboard. It's a Gigabyte b450 aorus pro wifi. I have the Realtek audio console installed and when I plug in my headphones into the back of the motherboard it detects the headphones as double the ohms. My headphones are a pair of Sony MD-V6 (63 ohms) but when I plug them in, the computer is setting the ohms at 120 ohms [image: ohms headphones detection setting]

I've had Gigabyte motherboards in the past and they're fantastic in terms of sounds but when I watch movies or listen to music the sound is just off with this motherboard.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue or how to manually set the ohms settings anywhere for Realtek? Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure all the measurement is doing is changing the maximum output level to the headphones. Low impedance cans just need less power to push them loud. Since the popularity of low-power devices such as laptops & phones, it's easier & cheaper to make low-impedance headphones to match their poor power outputs, rather than have to make high quality driver amps that need to push more power to traditional high impedance cans. The impedance alone doesn't affact the sound… just the quality of the amp needed to drive them.

Comment: @Tetsujin Okay thanks. So the impedance has no effect on the quality of sound but just the volume? Is this correct?

Comment: It shouldn't *directly* affect the sound quality, however, low impedance headphones are much more subject to interference & other artefacts present in cheap, low-output amps. That's not really the headphones' fault, but what manufacturers can get away with to drive them.